# Bubble Sort in C but need to move anything with a 1 all the way to the bottom. I can use riders[i].withdrawn to access it

Tags: c, bubble-sort

```
void sortraceTime(struct RiderInfo *riders, int size){

 struct RiderInfo swap;
  int i = 0, j = 0, n = size;

 //Sorting using the Bubble sort technique

for (i = 0; i < n; ++i){
     for (j = i + 1; j < n; ++j){
         if (riders[i].raceTime > riders[j].raceTime){
             swap = riders[i];
             riders[i] = riders[j];
             riders[j] = swap;
         }//end if
     }//end inner for
 }//end outer for
    printf("\n");
    printf("--- Riders sorted by raceTime! ---\n");
    printf("\n");
}
```

Output-----------------------------------------------------------------------

0:24 -- S -- Jocelyn Lovell -- 1

1:50 -- S -- Angus Young -- 0

2:35 -- S -- Eddie Van Halen -- 0

3:08 -- S -- Billy F. Gibbons -- 0

3:38 -- S -- Nikki Sixx -- 0

4:19 -- S -- Charlie Watt -- 0

Answer (score 2):

You want to do a multikey sort.

Just add an extra state variable.

I've refactored your code and cleaned it up a bit. Note that because your code block was a bit sparse, I was unable to test this:

```
void
sortraceTime(struct RiderInfo *riders, int size)
{
    struct RiderInfo swap;
    struct RiderInfo *lhs;
    struct RiderInfo *rhs;
    int i;
    int j;
    int n = size;
    int needswap;

    // Sorting using the Bubble sort technique

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        lhs = &riders[i];

        for (j = i + 1; j < n; ++j) {
            rhs = &riders[j];

            needswap = 0;
            if (lhs->withdrawn > rhs->widthdrawn)
                needswap = 1;
            if (lhs->raceTime > rhs->raceTime)
                needswap = 1;

            if (needswap) {
                swap = *lhs;
                *lhs = *rhs;
                *rhs = swap;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\n");
    printf("--- Riders sorted by raceTime! ---\n");
    printf("\n");
}
```